# OpenVPN , internet browsing using distant IP?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN to access one of our subsidiaries local apps and network..
i was wondering if it would be possible to browse internet using the distant network public ip ?
my computer (public ip : 1.1.1.1) , is connected thru openVPN to a network (public ip : 2.2.2.2)
I want my computer to browse internet with 2.2.2.2 as public ip address

Is it possible  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, depending on your firewall and VPN setup.  What you want to do is called *hairpinning.*